# Recover the directory structure of a lost LVM Logical volume?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, backup, data-recovery, lvm

I am aware of the huge amount of data recovery questions on this site, and reading all of them I think my case is unique enough to warrant a new question.

#### how it came to be

I set up a LVM with individual LV for each part of the system over two disks

```
$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1            8:1    0 931.5G  0 part 
  └─datavg-data 254:4    0 543.8G  0 lvm  /data
sdb               8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2            8:18   0   244M  0 part /boot
└─sdb3            8:19   0 111.1G  0 part 
  ├─notapc-root 254:0    0   5.5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─notapc-usr  254:1    0   8.5G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─notapc-var  254:2    0   4.8G  0 lvm  /var
  └─notapc-home 254:3    0  91.2G  0 lvm  /home
```

(I can give you the output of `lvdisplay` too, but I though it to long and unimportant

`apt`/`dpkg` started complaining about a lack of space on `/var`, `/` etc. so I decided to size them up. I also decided to decrease the size of my home partition, as most it was just symlinks (e.g. ~/Downloads to /data/username/Downloads/ anyway. So I just used lvreduce *< whoops>* **before shrinking the filesystem** *< /whoops>*.
as expected, the filesystem could not be mounted on reboot. Since there was no important data I simply `dd if=/dev/mapper/notapc-home of=/data/brokenhome.bak` and made a new FS on the LV.

I later discovered that I never symlinked my projects folder to `/data`, which means it never landed on a Backup (I only backup `/data`), which made me really glad I dd'd it.

unfortunately I really struggled finding programs that could help me recover the partition. Testdisk would require my disk to still be intact, and I could not find more programs that can rebuild more than the partition table. `Strings` finds tons of stuff, which made me think maybe my project files could be recovered.

How do I recover a LVM LV partition with 2G missing from the end from a file image of the partition?